# Angular Material mat-me

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

1) Open a folder with several files.
2) Right click on a file and the context menu shows.
3) Right click on another file and the first menu close and a new context menu opens. (One click required)

I find that with mat-menu, you need to click out off the menu and click again to open a new menu. How do I change mat-menu so it works like the above example?

I tried to modified this example, https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-nested-menu-yclrmd?embed=1&file=app/nested-menu-example.html.

Should actually close not hover.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hover event on menus and based on that event open another menu. Mat Menu has api for focus specific menu.